# How to show the specific customer name appear at the next form when the customer login

Tags: c#, windows, web-applications

After I create the login part, then I wish to fetch the customer ID by showing the customer name in the next form. For example, the user login with username and password then their name will appear at the next form e.g.Hi Alice

I am using window form application.

Here is my login file:

```
public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\xchoo\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication_test2\WindowsFormsApplication_test2\Data.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
           // DBConnection();

            {
                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Count(*) From custInfo where Username='" + USERNAME.Text + "'and Password='" + PASSWORD.Text + "'", con);

                // con.Open();
                DataTable custInfo = new DataTable();
                //con.Close();
                sda.Fill(custInfo);

                if (custInfo.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
                {
                    this.Hide();
                    Select_Item select_item = new Select_Item();
                    select_item.Show();
                    con.Close();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please check your Username and Password");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my database table:

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[custInfo] (
    [cust_Id]      INT        NOT NULL,
    [USERNAME]     NCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
    [PASSWORD]     NCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
    [companyName]  NCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
    [Cust_phone]   NCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
    [Cust_address] NCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([cust_Id] ASC)
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending how your application is structured here's one solution.

Create a constructor for the next form like this:

```
public Form2(string username)
{
  InitializeComponent(); 
  labelUsername.Text=username;
}
```

Pass the username to the form:

```
string username = "username"; // grab it from the database
Form2 frm=new Form2(username);
frm.Show();
```

Link to tutorial:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14122/Passing-Data-Between-Forms

Answer (score 0):

> string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;

I hope it helps.

Comment: the "Name" i mention is not the computer window login name. I create an invoice window form application using C#, there is a login part. I wish to use the login detail, e.g. Alice login credential is : USERNAME:Alice, PW:123, then the next form will have "Hi Alice" at the top. In another case, if the Kelvin then will have hi Kelvin appear in the form. The name I mention is not the pc window name. Btw, this works in pc window name.